How to convert Figma to Qt
I trying to make Qt code for UI on python and I have Figma reference.
I tried to convert it to *.qtbridge file but in the end its not suits me. I suspect i need QML format to make qt from it.Or any other approaches that can help?

Your question is unclear. If you did try to convert it, and succeeded, what did not "suit" you? Have you followed the Qt guidelines? Please read [ask].

Figma Qt Bridge is not available to developers with Community Edition License. If you have license other than Community Edition, you will need to import your *.qtbridge file to Qt Design Studio project.
